# scala list of objects, using groupBy with average

Tags: list, scala, group-by

basically I'm not really a Java/Scala fan, but unfortunately I'm forced to use it for my studies. Anyways, I was given an assignment:

What the program gets is a list of objects like: `Mark(val name String, val style_mark Int, val other_mark Int)`.

How can I use groupBy, to group the marks by name, and get an average for style_mark and other_mark?

```
Mark("John", 2, 5)
Mark("Peter", 3, 7)
Mark("John", 4, 3)
```

Should return:

```
Mark("John", 3, 4)
Mark("Peter", 3, 7)
```

Thats the code:

```
class Mark(val name: String, val style_mark: Int, val other_mark: Int) {}

object Test extends Application
  {
  val m1 = new Mark("Smith", 18, 16);
  val m2 = new Mark("Cole", 14, 7);
  val m3 = new Mark("James", 13, 15);
  val m4 = new Mark("Jones", 14, 16);
  val m5 = new Mark("Richardson", 20, 19);
  val m6 = new Mark("James", 4, 18);

  val marks = List(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6);

  def avg(xs: List[Int]) = xs.sum / xs.length

  marks.groupBy(_.name).map { kv => Mark(kv._1, avg(kv._2.map(_.style_mark)), avg(kv._2.map(_.other_mark))) }

  println(marks);
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already said, we can use `groupBy` to group the Marks by name. Now we have a `Map` where each key is the name and the value is a list of Marks with that name.

We can now iterate over that `Map` and replace each key-value pair with a Mark-object that has the key as its name, and the average of the `style_mark`s in the list as its `style_mark` and the average of `other_mark`s in the list as its `other_mark`. Like this:

```
def avg(xs: List[Int]) = xs.sum / xs.length
marks.groupBy(_.name).map { kv =>
  Mark(kv._1, avg(kv._2.map(_.style_mark)), avg(kv._2.map(_.other_mark)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I sort of get it. Updated my question with the code that I have right know, but its giving me an error `error: not found: value Mark` at `Mark(kv._1,...`

Comment: @Pawel: If `Mark` is not a case class, you need to write `new Mark(bla,bla,bla)` instead of `Mark(bla,bla,bla)`.

Comment: @Pawel: Also note that the value of `marks` will remain unchanged, so you should print the return value of the expression, not the value of `marks`. (Though it's easier to test code in the REPL than by creating a file and running it, in which case you can just enter the expression and will see its result).

Answer (score 7):

Just a couple of points here:

1. You can use pattern matching to avoid all that tedious _1, _2 stuff that comes with tuples.
2. Underscores in variable/parameter names are a Bad Thing™, they're already used far too heavily elsewhere in the language

So having stated that:

**UPDATE:** replaced `avg` with `avgOf`, reducing duplication :)

```
//Needs two param lists so that inference will work properly
//when supplying the closure
def avgOf[T](xs:List[T])(f:(T)=>Int) = xs.map(f).sum / xs.length

marks.groupBy(_.name).map {
  case (k,v) => new Mark(k, avgOf(v)(_.styleMark), avgOf(v)(_.otherMark))
}
```

In the real world, I'd probably pimp Traversable to add the `avgOf` method, so you could write `v.avgOf(_.styleMark)`, but that would just complicate this example.

Comment: There should be `case` before `(k, v)`.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time I've made that mistake either :)